# How to write a spec file not to run ./configure in CentOS7

Tags: rpmbuild

I have written spec file just copy some files to some directory on CentOS7.

```
...(snip)...

%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install
install -m 644 -p $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/some/file \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_sysconfdir}/file

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%doc
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/some/file

--------

$ cd rpmbuild
$ rpmbuild SPECS/my.spec
...(snip)...
+ ./configure --build=x86_64 ...
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.RidAmi: line41: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I have not written `./configure ...` anywhere.
I don't know why rpmbuild fails.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here.
Looks like deleting %build line.
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51254

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will summarize the procedure I thought it had resolved. Please wait.